# Getting while capturing file using bat file in java

Tags: java, maven, pac4j

javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] is not found with the qualifiers
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Method Injection Point, method name :  getWebContext, Bean Owner : [WebContext, WebBeansType:PRODUCERMETHOD, Name:null, API Types:[java.lang.Object,org.pac4j.core.context.WebContext], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any], Producer Method: org.pac4j.core.context.WebContext org.pac4j.jee.util.Pac4jProducer.getWebContext(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
we are getting above error while we capturing file using java
`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-pac4j</artifactId>
<version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>`
```

causing issue due to this above library. we cannot remove we have implement oidc using pac4j jar.

help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes (`Pac4jProducer` and `HttpServletResponseProducer`) are meant to use CDI and produces pac4j beans.

What is your application server? Can you copy/paste the full stack trace?